# How to run python code if pyenv is setup to run against multiple versions of python

Tags: python, python-3.x

We have our admin team setup PYENV so that we can run against multiple versions of python.

we have two versions of python Python 2 and Python 3. How do I run my scripts against python 3?

For example, when I just run like Python test.py it always run against python2 but I want to run my script with Python3.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you asked your admin team?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using mac in terminal write ( python3 (name of the file).py

Answer (score 0):

That depends.

If you want to use `python3.x` globally, you can run `pyenv global 3.x` to set the specific python version you want as your global version.

However, if you want to use `python3.x` for that specific script only, run 
`python3.x path/to/specific/script.py`